# How to choose the column to update depending on the values

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a table with 1 primary key column a, 1 not nullable foreign key column b and 5 nullable foreign key columns c, d, e, f, g.

I have to insert the value Y in the row where the value X is the primary key:

- if X is not present in the table, I have to create a new row with:

  ```
  INSERT INTO table(a, b) VALUES (X, Y)
  ```
- if X is present in the table and b contains a value, I have to set Y in the c column:

  ```
  UPDATE table SET c = Y
  ```
- if X is present in the table and b and c contain a value, I have to set Y in the d column:

  ```
  UPDATE table SET d = Y
  ```

and so on; if the row is full, nothing must happen.

How can I translate this in a working query? Note that I'm using MySQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to update the row with the key `X` if it exists. A column needs to be set to `X` if it is `NULL` and its "predecessor" is not `NULL` (except for `c` as `b` is declared  `NOT NULL`). That can be expressed with [`CASE ... END`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

```
INSERT INTO table
            (a,
             b)
            VALUES (X,
                    Y)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = CASE
                                     WHEN c IS NULL
                                       THEN Y
                                     ELSE
                                       c
                                   END,
                               d = CASE
                                     WHEN d IS NULL
                                          AND c IS NOT NULL
                                       THEN Y
                                     ELSE
                                       d
                                   END,
                               e = CASE
                                     WHEN e IS NULL
                                          AND d IS NOT NULL
                                       THEN Y
                                     ELSE
                                       e
                                   END,
                               f = CASE
                                     WHEN f IS NULL
                                          AND e IS NOT NULL
                                       THEN Y
                                     ELSE
                                       f
                                   END,
                               g = CASE
                                     WHEN g IS NULL
                                          AND f IS NOT NULL
                                       THEN Y
                                     ELSE
                                       g
                                   END;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns me an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET c = CASE
                                         WHEN c' at line 7

Comment: I think you should have removed the SET in "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET", it seems to work now. However, thank you a lot!

Comment: @Snorlite: Argh, yes. When your used to certain keywords coming together... I corrected the code.

Comment: I also inverted the updates order: after the c update, the query doesn't stop and it inserts Y in d, e, f and g also immediately. With the inversion I should have no problem